# What's a good name for an Enum for Yes & No values

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions, naming

## Background

In a C# command-line app I'm writing, several of the parameters have "yes" and "no" as the possible values.

I am storing their input using the Enum type shown below.

```
enum YesNo
{
     Yes,
     No
}
```

Which is fine - the code works. No problem there.

NOTE: Yes, I could store these as bool (that's how it used to work). My design choice is to be explicit about the Yes/No choice made by the user because they will see this printed in other contexts and I'd like it to be more obvious what the choice was.

## My Question

- It just seems odd to have an enum called "YesNo" - what are some suggestions for better names for an enum for "yes" and "no" values.

## So Finally

I asked this question relatively early in StackOverflow's life. It wasn't fake question - I really did have this situation.  I just thought it would be nice to use it see what the community would do. Because it is, I admit a somewhat  odd question.

First, thanks to all who spent the time replying. I'm trying to pay that back with a thoughtful conclusion.

Comments on the answers

**switching to bool**. I understand your motivation, but I feel I need to point out that having a **binary** choice (and by that I mean a choice between any two values - alive/dead, married/unmarried, etc.) is not the same as **boolean** choice between true and false.  We find as programmers switching between yes/no and true/false easy - fair enough. Had my choice in this case been for example "Democrat" or "Replication"" (contrived example, I know) then you can see possibilities for confusion or at least awkwardness. I do think the bool option is valid in this case, but less so in other binary choices.

**localization** - great point. In my specific case it didn't matter - this was not and is never going to be localized, but for other situations it is something to consider.

**more than three options** - In fact, later on I had to add a third value called to represent the valid (in my application) condition of a user specifically *not* making the choice.

There were a lot of good comments, thank you all!

Comment: Hmmm, maybe an "IDontKnow" will be added in the future? LOL

Comment: Actually something like that may occur for other parameters. 

    Examples: 
       Yes,No,Auto
       Yes,No,Inherit

Comment: This begs the question: what *would* be a good name for an enum that contained {Yes,No,Auto} or {Yes,No,Inherit}, etc..  I actually have used the former, and found myself with no good alternative to the name YesNoAuto, but I *hated* it and felt a little dumber every time I had to use it.

Comment: P.S. I used Auto = -1, No = 0, and Yes = 1.  So maybe I should have named it AutoNoYes. :)

Comment: Please don't do this to yourself. Stick with bool

Comment: What about `BinaryFlag`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a name that indicates the Value which is set to Yes or No.

E.G.

```
public enum Married
{
    YES,
    NO
}
```

Comment: There were a lot of good responses, but this one most directly answered the question.

Answer (score 39):

You say you don't want to use bool because it will be printed out for the user to see amongst other contents. That suggests the problem isn't in *storage* but in *display*. By all means present true/false as Yes/No, but there's no need to create a whole new type for it IMO.

EDIT: In addition to suggesting you don't use an enum in the first place, I'd strongly recommend that if you *do* use an enum, you change the order or use explicit values. Having Yes=0, No=1 will be really confusing if you ever end up seeing the values as integers.

Comment: Your observation is correct - what the enum does for me is just simplifies a very tiny part of the output generation. I could easily create a function called bool_to_yes_no() - but I thought it would be simpler to just write Console.Writeline("paramfoo: {0}", paramfoo )

Comment: If you restrict your storage mechanism to always be directly presentable to users, you're going to tie yourself in knots elsewhere, I suspect. I really would just translate it where appropriate. As a bonus, it's then easier for i18n...

Comment: bool answer = true;

string.Format("User enter {0}", answer ? "Yes" : "No");

Answer (score 8):

I would be confused to see an enum used for a boolean.  You say that:

> NOTE: Yes, I could store these as bool (that's how it used to work). My design choice 
>   is to be explicit about the Yes/No choice made by the user because they will see this
>   printed in other contents and I'd like it to be more obvious what the choice was.

I fail to see how a "Yes" or "No" is any more "explicit" than a true or false.

Comment: The users of the cmdline-app will not be so technical - I'd rather they see something that reflects what they typed. I'll take care of mapping to bool internally. Using an enum here is just a simple way for me to get the output to look correct for the end-user without too much effort on my part.

Comment: Managing data in a program and visualizing it to the user are two different things. You can use a boolean value and just translate it to you users on visualization. Since you enum is not multi-language this gives you more choices, too.

Answer (score 6):

- YesNo
- Choice
- BinaryChoice

Or just use a boolean.

Comment: That violates normal .NET naming conventions. "E" is not normally used as an enum prefix.

Comment: Is it not an enum?
*enum* YesNo
{
     Yes,
     No
}

Comment: @Burkhard: Yes, it's an enum. No, that doesn't mean it should be prefixed with an "E". It also shouldn't be plural as it's not a flags enumeration.

Comment: Um, not sure what your last comment is meant to mean, but my point is that enums in .NET *aren't* conventionally prefixed with an E, whereas all your suggestions are.

Comment: Unfortunately I now can't remove my downvote. Consider it removed *in spirit* though :)

Answer (score 6):

ResponseEnum or EResponse or UserResponse depending on your conventions.

I wouldn't limit yourself to only Yes or No as in the future you may want to add functionality that required an Unsure response also.

Answer (score 6):

I'd want to call it:

```
enum Boolean
{
     Yes,
     No
}
```

No, wait, there is already a built in boolean type you can use.

If your only reason for using an enum here is because there is a convenient conversion to/from a string that you want to show the user, then you are going to get bitten very badly down the track as you do more sophisticated things.  A separation of model from view will server you well.  Read up on MVC and/or MVVM patterns.

I might also suggest that a simple boolean with some custom attributes that define the display strings to use in place of "true" and "false" might suffice here.  You can then write your own to/from string methods that look for your custom attributes.

Answer (score 3):

(Humour - *please* don't take this seriously...)

I'm surprised no-one's suggested this yet:

```
public enum UserWtf
{
    No,
    Yes,
    FileNotFound
}
```

Comment: Only Paula would use Brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

I would not use a enum at all, just roll your own typeconverter and use booleans.

Answer (score 2):

I think YesNo is just fine. Consider things like "MB_OK" and "MB_YESNO" ... I know it's not a type but anything that's self-explanatory should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any possibility for having option other than yes/no.For just 2 option stick with boolean.Try to modify the display area alone

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is a problem with displaying bool values.
It is better to create simple wrapper that stores boolean allowing you to display them as Yes/No or True/False.

Answer (score 1):

EUserAction ?

You described it as some user action. You could also be more specific, though. The name allows for some additional choices in the future. (The name should be what the choice is for, not what the choices are)

However, for your other, subtle question:

> *because they will see this printed in other contexts and I'd like it to be more obvious what the choice was.*

it shouldn't really matter what the user sees. The data model can be very different from what you present to the user. A bool would have sufficed. Is there a possibility for additional actions in the future?

Comment: See comment to Burkhard. I'd also argue that "user action" is very vague - given *just* the name, what values would you expect to see?

Comment: It's related to the design. See how he described it :)
Also, the name allows for some additional choices in the future.
The name should be what the choice is for, not what the choices are.

Comment: Moogs - I understand what you are getting at. Although I'm not sure it helps me in this case (due various reasons relating to the specifics of the app) - I think your suggestion makes sense long term for my code.

Comment: @moogs: It still seems wrong to me. UserChoice would be better than UserAction (they haven't taken an action) but it still isn't self-explanatory - it doesn't say what *kind* of choice they've made. If you can't guess the kind of values for an enum based on the name, I'd say there's something wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet- if he was more specific about what kind of action it was (like SaveDocument or KillProcess) then I could give a more meaningful name.    namenlos?

Comment: @moogs: No, because the type of the response (yes or no) doesn't necessarily depend on the type of the question. Even BooleanChoice is more descriptive than "UserAction" - but then I don't think he should be using an enum anyway...

Comment: (Btw, I still can't see where you got the word action from - I can't see it in the question or in edits to the question. What am I missing?)

Comment: @jon skeet - ah, sorry to be vauge. He described it as "choice made by the user". It's storing some thing/response already done by the user.

Re-reading the comments, perhaps we're the same road. UserChoice and UserAction are both vague to me. He should give more details on the use.

Answer (score 1):

I read your updated explanation, but I still feel this is a poor choice.  Booleans exist exactly for this purpose.  It is *your* responsibility to ensure that  when "they will see this printed in other contents" appropriate text is outputted.  This could be as simple as:

Console.WriteLine(_("Using Foo: ") + (useFoo ? _("Yes") : _("No")));

while still having full support for localization.  useFoo is of course a parameter telling the function whether it is using foo. :)

The _ is short for the gettext function (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), which is available for C# (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/gettext/C_0023.html).

Answer (score 1):

When I have need something like this, I use the word Flag, as in `Flag.Yes`, `MarriedFlag.No`, etc.

Example of when this is useful: you know there are only Yes and No values today but you suspect there might be additional values (like Maybe) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I use OptionalBinaryFilter for:

Yes, No, All

But if you have only Yes and No, seem more suitable use of Boolean in a member.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of this enum unless there were some other values besides Yes and No. That's just a bool. And making an enum just so you don't have to type out yes or no seems kind of silly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bool, combined with bool.TrueString and bool.FalseString for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Confirmation {
    Yes = 'yes',
    No = 'no'
}
```

or

```
enum Confirmation {
    Yes = '401efbce-ad94-41cf-94cf-2313611e94c2',
    No = '8f836daa-40fb-46ec-9708-28a40bc6fead'
}
```